# Can the sum of finitely many inverses of distinct odd integers $\geq 3$ be 1?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there a positive number $n$ of distinct odd integers $z_1,z_2, \ldots, z_n \geq 3$ such that $\frac{1}{z_1} + \frac{1}{z_2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{z_n} = 1$?

Comment: $$\frac13+\frac15+\frac17+\frac19+\frac1{11}+\frac1{15}+\frac1{35}+\frac1{45}+\frac1{231}=1$$ See section 9.5 of [Egyptian fractions](https://r-knott.surrey.ac.uk/Fractions/egyptian.html#section9.5) written by Dr. Ron Knott.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In 1954, it was shown by [Stewart and Breusch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction#Open_problems) (independently) that if $\frac {p}{q} >0$ and $q$ is odd, then it can be written as the sum of finitely many reciprocals of odd numbers.

As a specific example,

$$1=\frac {1}{3} + \frac {1}{5} + \frac {1}{7} + \frac {1}{9}  + \frac {1}{15} + \frac {1}{21} + \frac {1}{27} + \frac {1}{35} + \frac {1}{63} + \frac {1}{105} + \frac {1}{135}$$

Comment: A similar question, are there infinitely many such nontrivial representations? By what you said, we can continually decompose each of the above fractions, but we will always get that the sum of finitely many of them will be, say $\frac{1}{3}$. Is there a representation that doesn't use $1/3$ (or any particular fraction)?

Comment: @Clayton You can certainly repeat this procedure infinitely often with the smallest fraction. There is a lower bound on the number of representations with an odd number of terms, and I think it grows exponentially. (There is clearly no way to do it with an even number of terms).

Comment: @SteffenSchuler That's a very different question though.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution: 1=1/3+1/5+1/7+1/9+1/11+1/13+1/23+1/721+1/979007+1/661211444787+1/622321538786143185105739+1/511768271877666618502328764212401495966764795565+1/209525411280522638000804396401925664136495425904830384693383280180439963265695525939102230139815

You may have to verify it via symbolic softwares.